# Conditional distribution from the sum of uniform distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convolution, conditional-probability

I am trying to find the conditional probability distribution function of $Y$ $$F(Y\mid X_1,X_2)$$
given that $Y$ is distributed uniformly on $[0,1]$, 
$$X_1=Y+Z_1$$ and $$X_2=Y+Z_2$$
where $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are also drawn independently from each other and from $Y$ according to the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.

How does the result change if we have $X_1=m Y+nZ_1$ for some real $m,n$?

It seems to be an easy question, but I cannot come to any meaningful answer. Thank you for any hints.

Comment: It is not an easy question, though might be slightly easier if $Y,Z_1,Z_2$ had independent normal distributions

Comment: Thank you. For the normal distributions it is easy, I know the answer... It is also easy for $F(Y\mid X_1)$. But either I am too dizzy or it is indeed difficult, I really cannot see for $F(Y\mid X_1,X_2)$..